# Ionic angular error module undefined

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, webpack

my project is compiled in terminal correctly but at the time of opening the file I get this in the console of errors.

[image]

Comment: Can you add more information, like what file are you trying to open? Can you show us some code too ?

Comment: the code not is the problem, compiler work fine, when try the open index with build.js these error show the console